# How to clear directory/inode cache on MacOSX

Tags: performance, macos, shell, caching, filesystems

How to clear file system cache (e.g. directory cache and inode cache) on a Mac OSX? I would like to do some performance analysis on a cold MacOSX machine. I am wondering that is there any approach like `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` on a Linux box?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

is `purge(8)` any use to you?

> Purge can be used to approximate initial boot conditions with a cold
>   disk
>        buffer cache for performance analysis. It does not affect anonymous memory that has been allocated through malloc, vm_allocate, etc.