# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches on Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, command

Linux's command

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I read this command in URL:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58553/how-to-clear-memory-cache-in-linux

What command is similar on Mac?

Comment: There's a separate StackExchange for OS X support.

Comment: (Also, that's specifically a Linux command, not a UNIX command; procfs is very, very OS-dependent).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696978/how-to-clear-directory-inode-cache-on-macosx

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On OSX there is a `purge` command for that:

```
sync && sudo purge
```

> `sync` - force completion of pending disk writes (flush cache)
>
> `purge` - force disk cache to be purged (flushed and emptied)